# In Perl, how do I safely create a temporary FIFO?

Tags: perl

To compare with [`diff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/#Overview) adjacent records from a file, I created two [FIFOs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man7/fifo.7.html), forked children to supply their write ends, and captured the output of

```
diff -ub $previous $current
```

where the scalars contain the FIFOs’ paths—kind of how [`bash` process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) works.

This is not a program that needs to be bullet-proof, but if it were, how would I create temporary FIFOs so as to avoid [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and other vulnerabilities? Imagine [`File::Temp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp) has a `File::Temp::FIFO` cousin: what would be the latter's implementation?

Comment: With bash process substitution, each process in the pipe is complete before the `diff` ie, `diff <(ls $first_directory) <(ls $second_directory)` each `ls` is complete in total before `diff` is run on their outputs. You are trying to do the same record by record...

Answer (score 8):

How about creating a temporary directory (a la mkdtemp()) to avoid race conditions, and then put your FIFOs in there?

For example:

```
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);
use POSIX qw(mkfifo);

my $dir = tempdir(CLEANUP=>1);
my $fifo0 = catfile($dir, "fifo0");
mkfifo($fifo0, 0700) or die "mkfifo($fifo0) failed: $!";
my $fifo1 = catfile($dir, "fifo1");
mkfifo($fifo1, 0700) or die "mkfifo($fifo1) failed: $!";

print "FIFO #0: $fifo0\n";
print "FIFO #1: $fifo1\n";
```

Comment: Why two directories?  At least twice as much cleanup needed.  One directory is sufficient.

Comment: Hmmm.. I was being too clever for my own good.  You're right, only one temp directory is necessary.

Comment: Don't forget to check that `tempdir` succeeded.

Comment: tempdir() already die's upon error for me.  E.g. If I have it call tempdir(DIR=>"/etc") on Linux, it die's with "Error in tempdir() using /etc/XXXXXXXXXX: Parent directory (/etc) is not writable".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all the process ends are connected to the FIFOs you created, can't you just remove them from the filesystem?  The opened filehandles will keep the FIFO from being deleted, but no new handles could be attached to it, and once the existing filehandles are closed, the FIFO itself will disappear.

Comment: On Unix, you should be fine - I can't answer for Windows.  The other issue I see is does `mkfifo` follow incomplete symlinks?  On MacOS X, both the shell command and the system call fail with EEXISTS.  Choosing random names for the FIFOs should help, too.

Comment: My question centers on creating the FIFOs, but this answer seems to assume them as given. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, you mentioned in your question that "I created two FIFOs"?  Either way, you can create them with the `mkfifo` or `mknod` system commands.

Comment: As with creating temporary files and `open`, creating a temporary FIFO *safely* is more involved than a simple call to `mkfifo`, *cf.* the [source of `File::Temp`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TJENNESS/File-Temp-0.22/Temp.pm).

Comment: I was addressing the temporary nature of the FIFOs, and getting distracted from the creation part.  For that, I believe @Michael's answer might be your best bet - create a safe, temporary directory, and create your FIFOs within it.  Since directory creation is atomic, it's easy to use them as locks/race condition busters.